# Shortcuts app for my appintent in flutter plugin?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-plugin, sirishortcuts, appintents

I refer to having the App Intents looking like these widgets inside the Shortcuts app. Is that possible or only reserved for Flutter Plugin and Flutter Apps?

[image]

Integrate Siri shortcuts AppIntents in Flutter Plugin and/or Flutter Apps